# How to find where CSS class in being used in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I am working on a WordPress site, it's a doctor directory where you can come and book appointments. Now I want to make clear that the tech support for this theme is very poor. So most of the design issues are being fixed by me using custom CSS until they fix the issue in an update. Now on the site, there's some CSS
`.dc-consultation-title {overflow: hidden;}` which is causing the names of the patients to disappear in the feedback section.

[image]

Now once I disable that code via Inspect Element the names start to show up.

[image]

Now what I want is to find out which other sections this same code is being applied on so if it doesn't break the design I could remove it or at least change the class so this will only apply to that. Because in mobile view the names does not disappear with or without it.

Mobile View With Code:

[image]

Mobile View Without Code:

[image]

Now what I don't understand is the code is not being overwritten by anything in either views mobile or desktop then why it is behaving differently? I also don't have any of my custom CSS for this class, can I add a inline CSS for a specific section so I won't be disabling that for the whole site but for that feedback section only? I do understand some PHP, enough to edit it. Just don't know where to look.

**Edit:**  what if I over write the CSS starting a bit higher in the HTML tree something like this `.dc-feedback-content .dc-consultation-details .dc-consultation-title { overflow: visible; }` how many chances are there that this will break something else?

Answer (score 0):

Please process through the below steps:

After following this you are able to find where the CSS class is being used.

Go to wp-content > themes > YOUR THEME-NAME and try to finder a folder that houses the CSS files. They are usually named CSS stylesheets or styles. You can then choose to download it and edit it with a text editing program on your computer. After editing, head to the same directory you found the CSS files and hit upload.

Comment: I think I am unable to explain What I want. I know where the stylesheet file is I also that this code is on line 6744 in the style.css file. What I want to know is that if I edit the CSS at line 6744 which is `.dc-consultation-title` will it break the design? let's suppose the CSS class `.dc-consultation-title` is being used somewhere else on the site and not just the feedback section, so by editing the code on line 6744 will fix my issue but will break the other section that I don't know about, I want to find out where else on the site the class `.dc-consultation-title` is being used.

Comment: For that you need to inspact every pages & search via that class either that class used or not.

That is only the solution to check .

Comment: not the best solution I was looking for but let's see.